# How to Parcelize a HashMap using Kotlin's Parcelize?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

This is what I have for trying @Parcelize a HashMap

```
@Parcelize
class DataMap : HashMap<String, String>(), Parcelable
```

But it can't even compile with the following code.

```
val data = DataMap()
data.put("a", "One")
data.put("b", "Two")
data.put("c", "Three")

val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(DATA_MAP, data)
startActivity(intent)
```

It complains at this line `intent.putExtra(DATA_MAP, data)` with error:

```
Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.

public open fun putExtra(name: String!, value: Parcelable!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent

public open fun putExtra(name: String!, value: Serializable!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
```

Comment: Since `HashMap` is `Serializable`, and since `String` is `Serializable`, why do you need/want `Parcelable`?

Comment: This is a map object embedded in another object, and the another object need to implement Parcelable, hence this needed to be parcelized.

Comment: Try `intent.putExtra(DATA_MAP, data as Parcelable)`.

Comment: It compiles by casting it to Parcelable, but the data is not passed to the destination activity, the returned data is null from this `val data = intent.extras.getParcelable<DataMap>(DATA_MAP)`

Comment: OK, let's then back up a step. Why are you passing this complex data structure between activities? `Intent` extras are for identifiers, flags, and not much more. Why is this not one activity with two fragments (so you no longer are limited by `Parcelable`) or two activities with a repository (where the second activity gets an identifier to retrieve the cached data from the repository)?

Comment: right, the current implementation of the app I'm working on does not have the best architecture, and it will require a lot of refactoring/efforts/challenges to just pass an id and have the destination class to get the complete data itself. Is it possible to parcelize a HashMap using Kotlin's @Parcelize annotation?

Comment: I would have expected it to work the way that you have it. You might try running a manual test of putting one in a `Parcel` and trying to get it back out again, to see if that gives you any clues as to what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `@Parcelize` only cares about primary constructor parameters, not about superclass; since you have none, the code it generates won't write or read anything from a `Parcel`.

So instead of extending `HashMap` (which is a bad idea anyway), you should make it a field:

```
@Parcelize
class DataMap(
    val map: HashMap<String, String> = hashMapOf()
) : Parcelable, MutableMap<String, String> by map
```

The `MutableMap<String, String> by map` part makes `DataMap` implement the interface by delegating all calls, so `data.put("a", "One")` is the same as `data.map.put("a", "One")`.

It also doesn't implement `Serializable` so you won't run into the same overload ambiguity.

You can see the list of supported types at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html and it does include `HashMap`:

> collections of all supported types: List (mapped to ArrayList), Set (mapped to LinkedHashSet), Map (mapped to LinkedHashMap);
>
> Also a number of concrete implementations: ArrayList, LinkedList, SortedSet, NavigableSet, HashSet, LinkedHashSet, TreeSet, SortedMap, NavigableMap, HashMap, LinkedHashMap, TreeMap, ConcurrentHashMap;

Comment: By making the map a field of the DataMap, the destination class is still not able to get the data, complaining `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable` on `val data = intent.extras.getParcelable<DataMap>(DATA_MAP)`

Comment: Strange error message, because I don't see why there should be such a cast in the first place. Sorry, but I can't say more without actually trying to debug this myself.

Comment: Actually, try to remove `MutableMap by` and call `data.map.put/get` instead of `data.put/get`. Maybe Android is trying to store it as a `Map`, then read it into a `HashMap`.

Comment: I do need it to be able to use `data.put/get`, it looks like the destination class can retrieve the `DataMap` if it is embedded as a field in another object like this: `@Parcelize
data class Data(val type: String, val map: DataMap) : Parcelable`